# Spray List Marshaller not found

Tags: scala, akka, spray, spray-json, spray-dsl

This code results in a compile error of `could not find implicit value for parameter marshaller: 
 spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller[List[akka.actor.ActorRef]]`.

I don't think the problem is the `ActorRef`, as changing this to `.mapTo[List[String]]` shows the same compile error

In general, it's somewhat confusing how spray does marshalling with all the implicits - is there a way to make this explicit e.g. `ListProtocol.marshal(value)`?

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import spray.http.HttpResponse
import spray.http.HttpRequest
import spray.http.Uri
import spray.http._
import spray.routing._
import HttpMethods._
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import akka.pattern.ask
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.Success
import scala.util.Failure
import spray.http.StatusCodes.InternalServerError
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._
import spray.httpx.marshalling._
import spray.http._

class HttpApi(val manager: ActorRef) extends HttpServiceActor {

  def receive = runRoute {
    path("nodes") {
      get {
        onComplete(manager.ask(NodeList())(3.seconds).mapTo[List[ActorRef]]) {
          case Success(value) => {
            // Compile error happens here
            complete(value)
          }
          case Failure(ex) => {
            complete(InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Followup thought - `spray-json` includes a marshaller for a List[T], wonder why that's not working here either

Comment: you need complete(value) + to have marshaller for ActorRef

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm still having the same issue, just now it's the proper compile error instead of the one resulting from me not using `complete(value)`

Comment: There is a default marshaller provided for List[T], so this should work for List[ActorRef], but I changed it to List[String] to be sure that was not the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this import

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
```

to

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
```

That is, you want to import the implicits defined in that object, not the object itself.

Alternatively you can extend the trait to pick up the implicits:

```
class HttpApi(val manager: ActorRef) extends HttpServiceActor
                                        with DefaultJsonProtocol {
```

Comment: So simple, but so hard to find. Thanks!

Comment: I know the feeling well!  Glad to help.